# How to search over and return elements of your knockout view model by some property

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a view model that has an `observableArray` of `timeSlices`.  Among other properties, each timeSlice has a time, place, and status.  When a user clicks on one timeSlice, I want to query the surrounding ones to test their status.

So basically, I want to search through my observableArray() at specific time/places to check other properties about the elements.  How can this be done in knockout?

Comment: timeSlices()[i].property?

Comment: You also may find useful this article by Ryan Niemeyer: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html. It has a description of ko.utils.arrayFilter method, which is what you need I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A knockout observable array is just a javascript array when unwrapped. You could use a computed if you want to associate a subset of items with the item just clicked

```
var samePlaceSlices = ko.computed(function() {
  // assumes you have observableArray called timeSlices
  var timeSlicesArr = timeSlices(),
      samePlaceSliceArr = [];

  // just loop through items like a normal array
  for(var i = 0; i < timeSlicesArr.length; i++) {

    // assumes slices have a property called place, not an observable 
    // and a single observable called clickedSlice that is the last clicked slice
    if(timeSlicesArr[i].place == clickedSlice().place) {
      samePlaceSliceArr.push(timeSlicesArr[i]);
    }
  }
  return samePlaceSliceArr;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use ko.utils.arrayFilter function, like that:

```
var filteredTimeSlices = ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.timeSlices(), function(timeSlice) {
        return timeSlice.place() == selectedPlace();
    });
```

Where selectedPlace() contains your selected filter value.